# how can i fit simple SVM method for prediction in python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm

I'm Trying to predict returns of EUR/USD .
But i have problem with fit option.
Here is the Code :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from sklearn.svm import SVC
```

and then getting data and split it to train and Test :

```py
# Getting Data
data = web.DataReader('EURUSD=X' ,data_source='yahoo' ,start = '2018-01-01', end= '2021-01-01')['Adj Close']

#Creating DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

## Calculating Returns
data['Return'] = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
data.dropna(inplace=True)

#here Specified Returns for training
Returns_for_Train_For_SVM = data.Return[ : int(len(data.Return)*0.8)]
```

Then The prediction Algorithm:

```py
svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')

X_For_SVM = np.arange(1 , len(Returns_for_Train_For_SVM)+1)
svclassifier.fit(X_For_SVM, Returns_for_Train_For_SVM)
```

when i run this code i get this error :

`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14. 15.  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.  25.  26.  27.  28. 29.  30.  31.  32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  37.  38.  39.  40.  41.  42. 43.  44.  45.  46.  47.  48.  49.  50.  51.  52.  53.  54.  55.  56. 57.  58.  59.  60.  61.  62.  63.  64.  65.  66.  67.  68.  69.  70. 71.  72.  73.  74.  75.  76.  77.  78.  79.  80.  81.  82.  83.  84. 85.  86.  87.  88.  89.  90.  91.  92.  93.  94.  95.  96.  97.  98. 99. 100. 101. 102. 103. 104. 105. 106. 107. 108. 109. 110. 111. 112. 113. 114. 115. 116. 117. 118. 119. 120. 121. 122. 123. 124. 125. 126. 127. 128. 129. 130. 131. 132. 133. 134. 135. 136. 137. 138. 139. 140. 141. 142. 143. 144. 145. 146. 147. 148. 149. 150. 151. 152. 153. 154. 155. 156. 157. 158. 159. 160. 161. 162. 163. 164. 165. 166. 167. 168. 169. 170. 171. 172. 173. 174. 175. 176. 177. 178. 179. 180. 181. 182. 183. 184. 185. 186. 187. 188. 189. 190. 191. 192. 193. 194. 195. 196. 197. 198. 199. 200. 201. 202. 203. 204. 205. 206. 207. 208. 209. 210. 211. 212. 213. 214. 215. 216. 217. 218. 219. 220. 221. 222. 223. 224. 225. 226. 227. 228. 229. 230. 231. 232. 233. 234. 235. 236. 237. 238. 239. 240. 241. 242. 243. 244. 245. 246. 247. 248. 249. 250. 251. 252. 253. 254. 255. 256. 257. 258. 259. 260. 261. 262. 263. 264. 265. 266. 267. 268. 269. 270. 271. 272. 273. 274. 275. 276. 277. 278. 279. 280. 281. 282. 283. 284. 285. 286. 287. 288. 289. 290. 291. 292. 293. 294. 295. 296. 297. 298. 299. 300. 301. 302. 303. 304. 305. 306. 307. 308. 309. 310. 311. 312. 313. 314. 315. 316. 317. 318. 319. 320. 321. 322. 323. 324. 325. 326. 327. 328. 329. 330. 331. 332. 333. 334. 335. 336. 337. 338. 339. 340. 341. 342. 343. 344. 345. 346. 347. 348. 349. 350. 351. 352. 353. 354. 355. 356. 357. 358. 359. 360. 361. 362. 363. 364. 365. 366. 367. 368. 369. 370. 371. 372. 373. 374. 375. 376. 377. 378. 379. 380. 381. 382. 383. 384. 385. 386. 387. 388. 389. 390. 391. 392. 393. 394. 395. 396. 397. 398. 399. 400. 401. 402. 403. 404. 405. 406. 407. 408. 409. 410. 411. 412. 413. 414. 415. 416. 417. 418. 419. 420. 421. 422. 423. 424. 425. 426. 427. 428. 429. 430. 431. 432. 433. 434. 435. 436. 437. 438. 439. 440. 441. 442. 443. 444. 445. 446. 447. 448. 449. 450. 451. 452. 453. 454. 455. 456. 457. 458. 459. 460. 461. 462. 463. 464. 465. 466. 467. 468. 469. 470. 471. 472. 473. 474. 475. 476. 477. 478. 479. 480. 481. 482. 483. 484. 485. 486. 487. 488. 489. 490. 491. 492. 493. 494. 495. 496. 497. 498. 499. 500. 501. 502. 503. 504. 505. 506. 507. 508. 509. 510. 511. 512. 513. 514. 515. 516. 517. 518. 519. 520. 521. 522. 523. 524. 525. 526. 527. 528. 529. 530. 531. 532. 533. 534. 535. 536. 537. 538. 539. 540. 541. 542. 543. 544. 545. 546. 547. 548. 549. 550. 551. 552. 553. 554. 555. 556. 557. 558. 559. 560. 561. 562. 563. 564. 565. 566. 567. 568. 569. 570. 571. 572. 573. 574. 575. 576. 577. 578. 579. 580. 581. 582. 583. 584. 585. 586. 587. 588. 589. 590. 591. 592. 593. 594. 595. 596. 597. 598. 599. 600. 601. 602. 603. 604. 605. 606. 607. 608. 609.]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

How can i fix this and predict for next days?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to train the SVM. Then you make predictions using the predict function. In the fit function, the first parameter that you have passed in an array of numbers from 1 to 609. And you are using the classifier. If you want to predict the EUR/USD, then it is a regression problem, that is, you want to predict some continuous values. Please refer to this documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html